# How can I build a printable table CSS 11x17 with header on every page

Tags: css, html, printing

So here is my challenge. I need to build a printer-friendly table in html/css that needs to meet a few requirements.

a) I am going to have an html table, with each row having adjustable heights depending on the amount of text in each row. A row cannot be "cut-off" at the end of a page and the start of the next page.

b) There is no defined number of rows per page, this needs to be flux depending on how many can fit.

c) every page must have the same header of a defined height.

d) The page must be printable on 11x17 paper with half inch margins.

Basically I am not sure how to approach this. I have built a normal  in html - but when printing the rows get cut off. I also am not sure how to figure out the "header" on every page requirement.

Any ideas on the best way I can approach this challenge?

Thanks!

Comment: If you need absolute precise control over print results, you'll want to produce a PDF. Browsers have too much control over the final output and too much variability and CSS is not really made for a page-based medium.

Comment: Any recommendations if I am outputting content from php to generate pdf's?

Comment: I've used FPDF before to build PDFs "by hand". It's horrible. I'm not sure there's a nicer alternative, but do have a good ol' Google. There must be a PDF library in some language that doesn't suck. :)